# How to use type of a class as a parameter?

Tags: java

How would I write and call the method `boolean doInstanceof(...)` which takes an Object `o` and a type `t` and returns true if `o` is an instance of `t`, returns false otherwise.

Something like:

```
boolean doInstanceof(Object o, type t)
{
    return o instanceof t;
}

//called like
boolean isInstance = doInstanceof(new MyClass(), MyClass.type())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and its `isInstance` method:

```
boolean doInstanceOf(Object o, Class<?> clazz)
{
    return clazz.isInstance(o);
}

boolean isInstance = doInstanceOf(new MyClass(), MyClass.class)
```

Mind you, that's only replacing one method call for another - you might as well call `Class.isInstance` directly:

```
boolean isInstance = MyClass.class.isInstance(new MyClass());
```

(I'm assuming that in reality you don't know the class at compile-time, otherwise you should just use `instanceof` of course.)